# deterministic stats_mode in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, stats_mode function selects the mode of a set of data.  Unfortunately, it is non-deterministic in picking it's result in the presence of ties (e.g. stats_mode(1,2,1,2) could return 1 or 2 depending on the ordering of rows inside Oracle.  In many situations this is not acceptable.  Is there a function or nice technique for being able to supply your own deterministic ordering for stats_mode function?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's web-page on [STATS_MODE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions139.htm) explains that `If more than one mode exists, Oracle Database chooses one and returns only that one value`.

As there are no additional parameters, etc, you can not change it's behaviour.

The same page, however, does also show that the following sample query can generate multiple mode values...

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT x, COUNT(x) AS cnt1 FROM t GROUP BY x)
 WHERE cnt1 = (SELECT MAX(cnt2) FROM (SELECT COUNT(x) AS cnt2 FROM t GROUP BY x));
```

By modifying such code you could once again just choose a single value, as determined by a specified ORDER...

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT x, MAX(y) AS y, COUNT(x) AS cnt1 FROM t GROUP BY x)
 WHERE cnt1 = (SELECT MAX(cnt2) FROM (SELECT COUNT(x) AS cnt2 FROM t GROUP BY x))
 AND rownum = 1
 ORDER BY y DESC;
```

A bit messy, unfortunately, though you may be able to tidy it slightly for your particular case.  But I'm not aware of alternative fundamentally different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the value among a set of values with the highest occurring frequency could also be done by counting and ordering.

```
select x from t group by x order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```

You can also make it deterministic by ordering on the value itself.

```
select x from t group by x order by count(*) desc, x desc limit 1;
```

I don't quite understand the complexity of Oracles query examples, the performance is really bad. Can anyone shine some light on the difference?

Comment: for oracle you need to use **where rownum = 1** instead of **limit 1**